How can I optimize this function? (Google Sheets)
I want a formula that takes in lines A1:A5 Then it takes the first letter of the word in A1 and put the first letter of the word in A2 behind it. Behind that the first letter of the word in A3. Et cetera. The result should look like this.
My only problem is that I can't use =SEQUENCE in =MID because then it does not take the first letter of the first word, then the first letter of the second word, et cetera. It will take the first letter of the first word then the second letter of the first word then the third letter of the first word, etc.
A formula that works is =CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(MID({$A$1:$A$5};1;1));" "));CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(MID({$A$1:$A$5};2;1));" "));CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(MID({$A$1:$A$5};3;1));" "));CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(MID({$A$1:$A$5};4;1));" "));CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(MID({$A$1:$A$5};5;1));" "))). We see the first part of =MID is first 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 and then 5.
But as you see this formula is really large and hard to expand. I want something more compact and general. AI couldn't help in this regard.
It works but is really large and unoptimized.

will you have more than 50k characters as final output?

No, I will not.

try:
=INDEX(JOIN(" "; SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(SPLIT(
 REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5; "(.)"; "$1×"); "×");;9^9); " "; )))




It seems to work fine. Thank you.
And if you don't mind, could you explain it. I try to learn sheets formulas

@BastianMüller sure. we use REGEXREPLACE to replace each character (.) with itself $1 and appending symbol × then we SPLIT by × and use QUERY to collapse all rows 9^9 into single row. next we remove empty spaces with SUBSTITUTE and JOIN all of it into one single cell separated with empty space " "


Here's one approach using mid and sequence:
=arrayformula(reduce(;sequence(max(len(A1:A5)));lambda(a;c;a&if(c=1;;" ")&join(;mid(A1:A5;c;1)))))


logic:

first letter (H) from all 5 words are picked → all H are
joined

now we move on to  sequence 2 letter (a) to pick them all →   all a are joined → now this is appended to the previous output of joined H's with a space b/w them

and the cycle continues until the max sequence is done.



A solution could be:
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ",BYCOL(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5,," ")," "),LAMBDA(c,JOIN(,c))))) 


Commented:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   JOIN(" ",                                   // 4. Concatenate the resulting 1D array into one cell with " " as delimiter
     BYCOL(                                    // 1. For each column 
       SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A5,," ")," "),    // 2. Take the array of splitted characters 
       LAMBDA(c,JOIN(,c)))))                   // 3. And concatenate it 

